# R Highcharter Map Error - Parse Error Trailing Garbage

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm loading a custom map as usual, but it ran into an error today - `Error: parse error: trailing garbage`. It seems like it relates to the JSON file parsing. I have tried a few other maps, but all had the same error.

Here is my code:

```
library(highcharter)
hcmap(map ="custom/world-highres2.js")
trying URL 'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-robinson.js'
Content type 'text/javascript' length 222031 bytes (216 KB)
downloaded 216 KB

Error: parse error: trailing garbage
      [6813,7340],[6842,7341]]]}}]};
                 (right here) ------^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definite fix but try installing the development version first:

```
remotes::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")

library(highcharter) 

hcmap(map ="custom/world-highres2.js")
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/741).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dev version works! Is there a way to save the map locally so it doesn't need to download the map every time I re-run my code?